# Plot facetted barchart using summary statistics within Python

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

Is there a concise way to plot summary statistics in Python as a boxplot?  The code below gives a barchart of each mean, I want to swap each barchart to a boxplot.

I realise that I don't need to summarise, however with the real data, just plotting one of the boxes took a long time (even with `showfliers=False`); I don't need to see the outliers and I will also want to add a "population-wide" bar (i.e. across all clusters) for each "pc" (any suggestions for that would be greatly appreciated .. I am again attempting to move from R to python and just getting these few lines of code took long enough)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
out = pd.DataFrame({'cluster':['a']*100+['b']*100,
                         'pc': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']*50,
                         'value': np.random.normal(size=200)})
grouped = out.groupby(['cluster', 'pc'])
out = grouped.describe()
out = out.reset_index()
out.columns = [e[0] if e[0] != 'value' else e[1] for e in out.columns.tolist()]

#sns.catplot(x='cluster', y='mean', col='pc', kind='bar', data=out)
g = sns.FacetGrid(out, col="pc", col_wrap = 2)
g = g.map(plt.bar, "cluster", "mean")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a boxplot from the summary statistics [using `Axes.bxp()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html?highlight=bxp#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp). This needs to be encapsulated in a custom plotting function passed to `map()`:

```
def my_bxp(**kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    color = kwargs.pop('color')
    bxpstats = []
    for _,row in data.iterrows():
        print(row)
        d = {'med': row.loc['50%'],
             'q1': row.loc['25%'],
             'q3': row.loc['75%'],
             'whislo': row.loc['min'],
             'whishi': row.loc['max'],
             'label': row.loc['cluster']}
        bxpstats.append(d)
    ax.bxp(bxpstats, showfliers=False, boxprops=dict(color=color), 
                                       whiskerprops=dict(color=color), 
                                       capprops=dict(color=color))
    

g = sns.FacetGrid(out, col="pc", col_wrap = 2)
g = g.map_dataframe(my_bxp)
```

[image]

Note that, for simplicity's sake, I have the whiskers extend from min to max, which is not the usual representation. You may have to calculate proper whiskers extents when you calculate your summary statistics if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to draw multiple boxplots with the original data intact.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster':['a']*100+['b']*100,
                         'pc': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']*50,
                         'value': np.random.normal(size=200)})
c = ['a']*25+['b']*25
df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(c), 
           df[df['pc'] == 'w']['value'].reset_index(drop=True), 
           df[df['pc'] == 'x']['value'].reset_index(drop=True), 
           df[df['pc'] == 'y']['value'].reset_index(drop=True), 
           df[df['pc'] == 'z']['value'].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df1.columns = ['cluster','w','x','y','z']


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(8, 4)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4)

ax = sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y='w', data=df1, orient='v', ax=axes[0])
ax = sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y='x', data=df1, orient='v', ax=axes[1])
ax = sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y='y', data=df1, orient='v', ax=axes[2])
ax = sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y='z', data=df1, orient='v', ax=axes[3])
```

[image]

Comment: I did try that, but it was taking a really long time (I didn't wait for it to finish).. I can provide details on amount of data and timing shortly (once I get some urgent work complete...).